# Workbooks.open return before focus (Excel 2010 and 2016)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that opens a new Workbook and then activate (focus) to first Workbook.

```
Code:
Set mainWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set bdWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="Another.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
mainWorkbook.Activate
```

I've got this code working in Excel 2007, but I've encountered an issue with the open workbook in Excel 2010 and later. The problem happens because Workbooks.Open returns to VBA before Excel Activate the new workbook [it works fine using debugger].

I can make an workarround using a `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))`, but......

**EDIT: My code that dosen't work in Excel 2016**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim path As String

    path = "A_PATH_FROM_MY_SERVER"

    actualScreenUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set MainWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=path, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=isReadOnly
    Set bdWB = ActiveWorkbook
    DoEvents

    MainWB.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = actualScreenUpdate

    With Sheets(MY_BD_SHEET)
        bdWB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy .[A1]
        '....
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `DoEvents` between the last two lines? Otherwise `but....` what?

Comment: Quick Question. Why do you want to `Activate` it? Not sure if you have see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179)

Comment: Hi @ScottHoltzman, DoEvents didn't work :-(

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I don't like to make workarrounds in my code. And how much wait do I need to put 1s? 10s?

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout, I don't use Select and Activate in my code... Thats why I want to Open() and stay in my main workbook.

Comment: I posted an answer. Check if that helps? You may have to refresh the page.

Comment: @Makah - sometimes "workarounds" are needed (if they are really even workarounds - all the time, I mean). What about just using a `With ` block to continue working on the `MainWorkbook` ... like `With Mainworkbook.Sheets(1) ...  .Range("A1").Value = "Working" ... more code here ... End With`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I have made a Class that I use everywhere `https://github.com/makah/ExcelHelper/blob/master/OCFile.cls` (comments in portuguese). I just want to addapt this class to work again.

Comment: I just saw your current edit :) Refresh the page and see the Edit that I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? (**Tried And Tested**)

This will open the relevant workbook and minimize it thereby returning focus to your main workbook.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wbThis As Workbook, wbThat As Workbook

    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbThat = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\Sample.xlsx")

    DoEvents

    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized

    ' OR

    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

After seeing your current Edit.

```
MainWB.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = actualScreenUpdate
```

You are activating when the `ScreenUpdating = False`? Set it to `True` and then Activate it :)

Comment: I'm curious if you tested this a large Excel file. I suspect the OP is opening a very big excel file and the code is moving faster then the file opens. However, I have not experienced this problem, as I usually notice that the code stops on the `Workbooks.Open` line until it actually opens.

Comment: I don't have a large file at the moment :P But I doubt the next line will run before that line is executed as the `Open` is happening from within Excel unlike the Shell Command. In such a case when you use Shell Command, the code moves on to the next line

Comment: @SiddharthRout are you using Excel 2016? Can you test my code?

Comment: No I don't have Excel 2016 at the moment but did you try `ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized`. Also set `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and then do what I said. By the way, I tried the above code in Excel 2010 and 2013 and it works. @Makah

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks! The problem was the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. I don't understand why Microsoft changed this. It seems that the `ScreenUpdating` makes the method returns before it should